# Truncate a string in bytes in Perl

Tags: oracle, perl

I am printing text on a PDF report using Perl. The data is coming from an oracle database table. I want to truncate the string to a specific size if it's longer than that size. I tried using the `substr` function but it seems like that's calculating in characters. I want to calculate the space taken up instead. This was my attempt:

```
$field_str .= ($totalwidth < 210) ? ' ' : "\n";
$field_str_trunc = substr( $field_str, 0, 278 );
```

This worked fine when the data was in all upper case; however, when I made it lower case and added more data, not enough data was presented on the PDF. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Each element of a string is a character. Those characters can be bytes, Unicode Code points, or anything else. /// It sounds like you have a string of Unicode Code Points, and that want the limit the size of its UTF-8 encoding. You don't have its UTF-8 encoding of the string, so getting that is the first thing you need to do.

Comment: It sounds like you want to truncate at a particular graphical length of the entire string (in pixels or whatever), not bytes.  Every character is the same number of bytes (except for special characters that take up 2 bytes, but generally all characters are a single byte). That doesn't mean they're all the same graphical length - that depends on the font.  You could use a fixed width font like Courier to get around that. Otherwise, you would have to retrieve the font details in order to calculate length.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`bytes`](http://metacpan.org/pod/bytes) pragma:

```perl
use utf8;
my $str   = "фуу";
my $chars = length($str);      # 3
{
    use bytes;
    my $bytes = length($str);  # 6
}
```